# Expressing the probability of a joint cumulative normal distribution in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Consider two random variables, $x$ and $y$, which are independent draws from the same normal probability distribution: $x,y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

I would like to calculate the probability that $x$ and $y$ fall on the same side of some threshold $c$. (That is, $x>c$ and $y>c$ OR $x<c$ and $y<c$.)

I think I am right that this equates to the sum of two probabilities:

1) $P(x>c,y>c) = (1 - \Phi(c))\times(1 - \Phi(c)) = (1 - \Phi(c))^2$

2) $P(x<c,y<c) = \Phi(c)\times\Phi(c) = \Phi(c)^2$

where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution. The answer I am looking for is therefore $(1 - \Phi(c))^2 + \Phi(c)^2$.

Questions:

1) Does the above make sense? I think that my presentation of this is probably somewhat laborious.

2) I would like to be able to relate this probability to the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ as well as the threshold $c$, but I'm stuck with this! I can see from simulations that as $\mu$ approaches $c$, the probability decreases, as it does when $\sigma^2$ increases, but I would like to be able to express this analytically if possible. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

3) I would also be interested in knowing whether there is a way of generalising this idea to other probability distributions. I have a feeling that this is probably something quite general, and would appreciate being pointed towards other things I could read about problems like this.

Comment: $P=\frac 1 2+ 2(\frac 1 2-\Phi(c))^2$ that is minimized when $\Phi(c)=\frac 1 2$ - that is $c=\mu$. You can also differentiate w.r.t to $\sigma$ to check the other quality.

Comment: Thanks for this. Would you mind explaining how you got from my answer to $P=\frac 1 2+ 2(\frac 1 2-\Phi(c))^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X, Y \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $$\Pr[(X < c) \cap (Y < c)] = \Pr\left[\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} < \frac{c-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \cap \left(\frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma} < \frac{c-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right],$$ and since these are independent, this becomes $$\Phi((c-\mu)/\sigma)^2.$$  Similarly, $$\Pr[(X > c) \cap (Y > c)] = (1 - \Phi((c - \mu)/\sigma))^2.$$  Therefore, the total probability is $$1 - 2 \Phi((c - \mu)/\sigma) + 2 \Phi((c - \mu)/\sigma)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks, this is really great. Two follow up points, if you have the time/inclination: 1) In the first step, you show that $\Pr[(X < c) \cap (Y < c)] = \Pr\left[\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} < \frac{c-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \cap \left(\frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma} < \frac{c-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]$. Apologies for being dumb, but I don't really understand why this is the case - is there a reference you could point me towards which explains this? 2) Do you have any thoughts about applying this to other types of probability distribution? Thanks again.

Comment: If $X < c$ then $X - \mu < c - \mu$, and $(X - \mu)/\sigma < (c - \mu)/\sigma$.  The point of doing this is because you specify $X$ and $Y$ to be normal with arbitrary mean and variance, but $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function for a **standard normal** distribution (mean 0, variance 1).  Hence you must standardize $X$ and $Y$ first.  This involves subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation, so if $X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $(X - \mu)/\sigma \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$.

Comment: Ah, great, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's OK ;)

Did you see the graphic of $\Phi'$ (density of normal)? In $x=\mu \pm \sigma$ change the convexity

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow?